# How do I find out which application plays sound?

Tags: sound, system-settings

So I keep having a sound that was playing often in the background and no event seems to be tied to it, that sounds very similar to service-login.ogg in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/`.

I don't know what other information to give but its driving me nuts and like I said I can't see any event or program that is causing it to happen.  Any help with what it is, or tracking it down is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a single chime? I've heard something like this, intermittently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find out which application plays this sound please open the *Sound Settings...* menu and watch the *Applications* tab while the sound plays:

[image]

On the command line we may also issue the following command to list various informations on a current audio stream through Pulse Audio:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

This will display not only the application streaming audio (`application.name`) but also the PID of this application (`application.process.id`) and information on the media content.

If we do not wish system sounds to play we can disable these in the *Sound Effects* tab from the *Sound Settings...* and see if the annoyance stops.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making this an answer, hopefully it will help other new users!

Comment: Any updates for 20.04?